# Removing comments from C++ string

Tags: c++, string, stream

I am trying to do a project that removes the comments from a previously written program. From what I have in theory it should work I think, but for some reason the output file is always empty in the end... Please help in any way you can... (P.S. Sorry if the indents are sloppy, copy and pasting never seems to work out well for me)

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <string> 

using namespace std; 


void comment_destroyer(ifstream&,ofstream&); 


int main (void) {


string filestart;  
string fileend;    
ifstream start;    
ofstream end;      


do {
    cout<<"Name of the file you want to remove comments from: ";
    cin >> filestart;
}  
while ( start.fail() );
cout << "What is the name of the file you want to call the stripped code?: ";
cin >> fileend; 

start.open ( filestart.c_str() );
end.open ( fileend.c_str() );

comment_destroyer (start, end);

start.close();
end.close();

return 0;
  }

// 
//Start of functions
//

void comment_destroyer(ifstream& start, ofstream& end){
    string line; 
    bool found = false;
    int i=0;

    while (! start.eof()){
        getline(start,line); 

        if (line.find("/*")<line.length())
        found = true;
        if (!found){
            for (int i=0;i<line.length();i++)
                {
                    if(i<line.length())
                    if ((line.at(i)=='/') && (line.at(i+1)=='/'))
                    break;
                    else
                    end<<line[i];
                }

        end<<endl;

        }
    if (found)
        {
            if (line.find("*/")< line.length())
            found == false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because comments are really annoying and just obscure the code?

Comment: To start with, don't do `while (!someFile.eof())`, it will not work as you expect. Instead do e.g. `while (std::getline(...))`. The reason is that the `eofbit` flag is not set until *after* you tried to read from beyond the end of the file. That means the first loop will iterate once to many.

Comment: You might want to think about your indentation as well, the indentation in the code you show makes it very hard to follow. Remember that you can always edit your question to fix these problems afterwards. Hint: The problems are most likely because the editor on SO don't handle tabs very well.

Comment: What is the implication of; line.find(/*) < line.length(). Remembering find() will give the position of first instance of the string

Comment: You also have a very big logical bug in the first `do ... while` loop in the `main` function. Remember that the file haven't been opened yet.

Comment: @Claptrap its for an assignment

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm going to have to read up on the flags and such, I didn't know that would loop too many times... And I will go through in a few minutes and fix up some of the indentation problems.. 
And how would you suggest fixing the error in the do...while?

Comment: @nom_nutella - Your checking for // is flawed.  You will go out of bounds here:
    `for (int i=0;i<line.length();i++) {`
     `if(i<line.length())`
      `if ((line.at(i)=='/') && (line.at(i+1)=='/'))`

The issue is that when `i == line.length()-1`, the condition `line.at(i+1)` is an illegal access.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie what do you mean by illegal access? I figured this would be the simplest way to check if there was another `/` after the first one... would you suggest a better way of doing this?

Comment: @nom_nutella - arrays, strings, basically most sequential containers are indexed from 0 to n-1, where n is the number of elements.  Look at your code carefully.  Assume that the string has 10 characters, so the maximum correct index into the string is 9.  What if i is equal to 9?  You are accessing line[i+1] which is line[10].  There is no line[10].  An illegal access like this (usually termed an "off-by-one" error) can cause programs to crash.

Comment: @nom_nutella -- In other words, your error is easily duplicated by placing `//` at the very end of the line.  So how to fix?  Well, it's your assignment -- all I can do is point out where your code will fail.  Since you're using the at() function, then you will have the benefit of an exception being thrown due to the index being out of bounds.  If you did use `[]` to index your string, then yes, your program may have crashed, or even "worked" (in other words, undefined behavior).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you, I am looking into it now to fix it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following section is erroneous. Instead of assigning false to found you use equality operator.

```
if (found)
    {
        if (line.find("*/")< line.length())
        found == false;
    }
}
```

Change `==` to `=`

```
if (found)
    {
        if (line.find("*/")< line.length())
        found = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Damnit its always the tiniest thing that causes the most problems.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think yur condition is wrong.
string.find returns std::string::npos if the searched term was not found. According to [npos](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/) this is -1, so the expression

```
 if (line.find("/*")<line.length())
    found = true;
```

always sets found to true.